# 8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (111)

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

Hello I run bitcoind and i get this 8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (111).
Can you help me with this? because it was working suddenly this happened.

Comment: my bitcoin.confıg is like this ( txindex=1
rpcuser=bitcoinrpc
rpcpassword=saadia
rpcbind=0.0.0.0
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0)

Comment: if you use the framework rpc the default port is 8332

Comment: when I run as testnet it works but when İ run as main it failed to connect. where can i change the port? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

this happens when you have a running daemon and suddenly for whatever reason the firewall starts blocking it. IT IS A FIREWALL ISSUE.

In my case I installed additional programs on my server which changed the settings of nftables (formerly iptables). I had to open up the relevant ports again (that are required by btc-daemon).

After that you have to restart both nftables as well as btcd.

Keep checking the logs for a few minutes. And you will see it will be running just fine.